# Close R plot window from emacs keybind

Tags: r, emacs, ess

Whenever I plot an R graphic in emacs ESS, it opens a new window. Is there a command to close it directly from emacs?

I was trying to create a keybind in my init.el file using something like

```
(setq ess-dev-off ‘(“dev.off()\n”)))
(eval-after-load “ess-mode”
  ‘(progn 
    (define-key dev-off “\C-cp” ‘ess-dev-off))
```

But of course is not working. Some advice on how to define my own keybind for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send R code to the inferior process using `ess-send-string`,

```
(defun my-dev-off ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((proc (ess-get-process)))
    (ess-send-string proc "dev.off()")))

(with-eval-after-load 'ess-r-mode
  (define-key ess-r-mode-map (kbd "C-c p") #'my-dev-off))
```

If you want to bind a function to a keybinding, the function needs to an *interactive* function, ie. one that is defined with  `(interactive)` as the first form in its body.